# Trouble with javascript injection

Tags: javascript, android, code-injection

I am trying to use a javascript injection to retrieve the element id of the button clicked. I then want to save this id to a string that I have created and then have it display into a toast that i have created. code is below:

```
 public static final String INJECTED_CODE = "javascript:"
        + "(function getClickedElement (id) { "
        + "Test = document.getElementById(id)"
        + "document.addEventListener('click', function(){Android.showToast(\'"
                                                               + Test 
                                                               +"\');});"
        + "})()";
```

I know that this works without adding in the `getClickedElement` bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without the getClickedElement inner function, because the part with

```
(
    ...some code
)()
```

is a self executing anonymous function, it executes itself immediately.

However when you add the inner function getClickedElement(id) you aren't calling it anywhere.

The code should look something like:

```
(
    document.addEventListener('click', 
        function(evt){if(evt.target.tagName == 'THE_TAG_OF_YOUR_BTN'){
                Android.showToast(evt.target.id);
            }
        }
    );
)()
```